# ng add @angular/fire Eresolve unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, npm, angularfire

This is the versions follow the commands that I used. Can you help me    resolve the issue? Thank you    ------------------------------------------------------ Angular CLI: 14.0.0 Node: 16.15.1 Package Manager: npm 8.11.0 OS: win32 x64
Angular: 14.0.0 ... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli,    core, forms ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Package                         Version    --------------------------------------------------------- @angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.0    @angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.0 @angular-devkit/core
14.0.0 @angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.0 @angular/fire                   0.0.0 @schematics/angular             14.0.0 rxjs                            7.5.5 typescript                      4.7.3    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
ng add @angular/fire Skipping installation: Package already installed    Package "@angular/fire" was found but does not support schematics.    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ng add @angular/fire@7.3.0 i Using package manager: npm ‼️ Package    has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.
The package @angular/fire@7.3.0 will be installed and executed. Would    you like to proceed? Yes npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local`    are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. npm ERR! code    ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR!    npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.0.0 npm ERR! Found:    @angular/common@14.0.0 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common npm ERR!    @angular/common@"^14.0.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR!    Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0    || ^13.0.0" from @angular/fire@7.3.0 npm ERR!    node_modules/@angular/fire npm ERR!   @angular/fire@"7.3.0" from the    root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict,    or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency    resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full    report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!        C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-04T17_59_45_994Z-debug-0.log    × Packages installation failed, see above.    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please format your answer and describe your issue a little more in depth, its unreadable this way

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem a few days ago. According to this Github issue: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3105

You can solve it by using the following commands (assuming that you already installed firebase via NPM)

```
firebase login
npm i -D firebase-tools
ng add @angular/fire@latest
```

and BTW: please make your question readable...